# UITextField w/ drop down button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

can a `UITextField` do this UI with codes alone or I need to use an image or use another component for this? like button,label.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
UIImageView *imgViewForDropDown = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
imgViewForDropDown.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropDown.png"];
yourTextField.rightView = imgViewForDropDown;
yourTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

For Swift Code:

```
let imgViewForDropDown = UIImageView()
imgViewForDropDown.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 48)
imgViewForDropDown.image = UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white")
yourTextField.rightView = imgViewForDropDown
yourTextField.rightViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    fileprivate func addBtnToTextField() {

    let dropDownBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    dropDownBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dropDownTringle"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    startDateTxt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    startDateTxt.rightView = dropDownBtn

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this by using `UITextField`,`UIButton` and `UITableView` with some animations,anyway Once have look at this example [ios dropdown](http://code4app.net/ios/comboBox/4f6817646803fa843f000006)

Comment: I don't need the tableview for the dropdown, i just need the UI but thanks.

Comment: do what do you like...:)

Answer (score -2):

*`UITextField` not provide this kind of feature*. you need to take a `UIImageView`, UIButton and `UITextField` , set a image in `UIImageView` which contain your textfield  background image, disable the UserInteraction property of textfield and keep it on a imageView , take a custom button without title and perform the action with button which you want.